# Android - How to create Excel sheet type layout?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want to create an Excel type layout where there is infinite scroll vertically. There are fixed number of columns horizontally, but they should be scrollable.

[image]

I tried the below code

```
 <HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/table_data_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

If I used the above code, then I am able to scroll vertically, but the columns are not scrollable.

Even giving fixed height in the xml for `HorizontalScrollView` and `RecyclerView`, the columns do not scroll.

Finally, I found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37619643/1237141), where it was advised to extend the `RecyclerView` and calculate the height dynamically.

```
 public class MySmartRecyclerView extends RecyclerView {

  public MySmartRecyclerView(Context context) {
    super(context);
  }

  public MySmartRecyclerView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
  }

  public MySmartRecyclerView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean canScrollHorizontally(int direction) {
    return false;
  }

  @Override
  public int getMinimumWidth() {
    return computedWidth;
  }

  @Override
  protected void onMeasure(int widthSpec, int heightSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthSpec, heightSpec);
    setMeasuredDimension(computedWidth, getMeasuredHeight());
  }

  @Override
  protected int getSuggestedMinimumWidth() {
    return computedWidth;
  }
}
```

So is this the only way, this can be achieved? Or is there any other way to achieve this. For RecyclerView inside `ScrollView` there is `NestedScrollView`, but no such thing for `HorizontalScrollView`.

Any pointers will be appreciated. TIA.

Comment: Have you got any hint?

Comment: @Muhamed: not yet..

Answer (score 2):

There is one alternate solution. You can use this [library](https://github.com/zhouchaoyuan/excelPanel).

Answer (score 0):

You want to do Ehhhh? Like the guy said, use library. You need and have normal easy to use solutions.

EDIT:

Okay my bad. 
You want to infinite scroll vertically, not excel. I'm back from excel topic:

at onScroll listener, you should incriment endlessly the totalItemCount, you do it with double recurssion. From within the function of listener, you call to another listner whereas you call it by a function in the middle, which also increments that number before calling to the same listener again. You simply edit the view and re-attach the listener.